# How do I get groups with the same number of students in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
TABLE students
(
    STUDENT_ID smallint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    GROUP_ID smallint,
);

TABLE groups
(
    GROUP_ID smallint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    GROUP_NAME char(5)
);
```

Each group has a certain number of students.

To find out, I use this query:

```
SELECT 
    groups.group_name, COUNT (*)
FROM
    students
JOIN 
    groups ON students.group_id = groups.group_id 
GROUP BY 
    groups.group_name;
```

Output:

| group_name | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| UH-76 | 27 |
| LQ-99 | 16 |
| UD-65 | 16 |
| MQ-93 | 23 |
| OC-92 | 23 |
| PF-42 | 22 |
| KZ-57 | 21 |
| NR-64 | 28 |
| WY-31 | 19 |
| TX-59 | 17 |

Now the question:

1. How do I get groups with the same number of students?

| group_name | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| "LQ-99" | 16 |
| "UD-65" | 16 |
| "MQ-93" | 23 |
| "OC-92" | 23 |

2. How do I get the groups with the least number of students?

| group_name | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| LQ-99 | 16 |
| UD-65 | 16 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get groups with the same number of students, you can assign a ranking, grouping on your counts_, then picking those which have at least a rank 2 (which means that at least one count_ is repeated twice).

```
WITH tab AS (
    SELECT groups.group_name, 
           COUNT(*) AS count_
    FROM       students
    INNER JOIN groups 
            ON students.group_id = groups.group_id 
    GROUP BY groups.group_name
), cte AS (
    SELECT group_name,
           count_,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY count_ 
               ORDER     BY group_name
           ) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT * 
FROM tab 
WHERE count_ IN (SELECT count_ FROM cte WHERE rn = 2);
```

Instead if you want to get the least number of students, it suffices getting all counts which value count is minimum, using a subquery:

```
WITH tab AS (
    SELECT groups.group_name, 
           COUNT(*) AS count_
    FROM       students
    INNER JOIN groups 
            ON students.group_id = groups.group_id 
    GROUP BY groups.group_name
)
SELECT * 
FROM tab 
WHERE count_ IN (SELECT MIN(count_) FROM tab);
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w7vkpyTaCDdNiqhcjQTnC/0).

Note that your initial query is employed within a common table expression inside these solutions.